# Drupal 8 REST api login via FB

Tags: facebook, rest, drupal-8

I am using **Drupal 8.x.** The requirement is User can login using FB via REST API call.

I am not understanding how to achieve this in Drupal 8. As for normal login I am using **simple_oath** module and it's working fine.

Has anyone know about, how to do this in Drupal 8.

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking. You can not log into to Facebook via API; that has to happen in the user’s browser.

Comment: Hi CBroe, the thing is that, from android device user can able to login via FB.

Comment: So I am not understand how to do this in drupal 8, how it will work?

Comment: Yes, login needs to happen inside a browser/webview, or one of their native apps. But what you actually want to know here, is still unclear.

Comment: Actually from Android App, user will try to login. Now Android developer will use Andoid Facebook SDK for that, they will send FB token to Drupal CMS via REST. Now Drupal has FB token, base on this FB token how to authenticate and authorize the user for other rest apis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module to login to Drupal via facebook + simple_oauth
https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth_facebook_connect